# How to ask user to enter a key for a hashtable and return the object value

Tags: java, input, hash, hashtable, key-value

I have a hashtable (theTable) with String usernames as keys and Object employees as values. I want to ask the user to input a username, and if the user inputs a username that's equal to a key in theTable, I want to return the employee object value.

```
System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String UserSearch = sc.nextLine();
    if UserSearch == theTable.get(key)(){
        return Employee;
    }
```

theTable.get will return the mapped key, but I'm not sure how to check/get the key to equal the entered username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use HashMap for this

```
Map<String, Object> theTable = new HashMap<>();
theTable.put("employeeId12345", new Employee());
System.out.println("Enter your username: ");
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String userSearch = sc.nextLine(); // assume it will return employeeId12345

if (theTable.contains(userSearch )){
  return theTable.get(userSearch);
}
```

Comment: Used a bit of a modified version of your code @Evilguy. Thanks for your help!